# Перенос вычислений с процессора на GPU

Tags: gpu, видеокарта

У меня есть программа, где нужно рисовать десятки тысяч разноцветных кругов и эллипсов. Но процессор одним потоком тянем максимум в 20 ФПС, а мне ядра процессора еще пригодятся. Как распараллелить кучу простых фигур, рисусющихся по данным из массива на GPU? Я уже скачал lwjgl, Видеокарта Nvidia, язык - java

Comment: А в каком языке то хоть? Какая видяха стоит?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону Direct3D и OpenGL и фреймворков на ваш язык которые их используют. Для любого, даже 10-летнего, GPU, отрисовать пару сотен тысяч кругов - не проблема.

Comment: java, видеокарта - Nvidia